# .NET Azure SDK - get raw response for async pageable result

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I'm using the lastest `Azure.ResourceManager` SDK for .NET to list all resources in a subscription, this works fine:

```
var armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

await foreach(var resource in subscription.GetGenericResourcesAsync())
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Got resource {id}", resource.Id);
}
```

However, I would like to get access to the raw HTTP response. [This article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Response.md) explains how to do this for other, non-pageable responses. So I'm looking for a way to do this in my case, too. Something like `GetRawResponse()` - but I don't have a response object.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like the following:

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var armClient = new ArmClient(credential);
var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
var allResources = subscription.GetGenericResourcesAsync();
await foreach(Page<GenericResource> page in allResources.AsPages())
{
   Response http = page.GetRawResponse();

   Stream contentStream = http.ContentStream;

// Rewind the stream
   contentStream.Position = 0;

   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(contentStream))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
   }
}
```

For more details, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/pagination